# org-reveal not exporting HTML presentation to slides

Tags: org-mode, reveal.js

I have followed the instructions from https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal/.
In my .emacs-file I have added:
;;;org-reveal
(require 'ox-reveal)
(setq org-reveal-root "file:///~/reveal.js-master").

Exporting  a simple "file.org" :
* Slide 1
* Slide 2
 * Slide 2.1
with with "C-c C-e RB" gives me a single continuous html-page without any slides:

Nikolai Stenfors
Created: 2017-01-10 tis 18:08
1 Slide 1
2 Slide 2
2.1 Slide 2.1

I'm probably forgetting something basic and simple, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This repository](https://github.com/smythp/org-reveal-config) contains the simplest possible org reveal setup. Clone or download the repository and open the presentation.html in Firefox or Chrome to see the slides or edit the presentation.org and export it to overwrite presentation.html.

Comment: Thank you, but no success. Should I copy the whole "reveal.js-master"-folder or just its subfolder "js"? Or should I alter something in .emacs?

Comment: It's possible to link to a copy of reveal elsewhere, but it's most straightforward just to copy the whole reveal folder to your project directory.

Comment: When you say a "continuous HTML page," what do you mean? You did open it in a browser, right?

Comment: Cloned the repo as you suggested. When I open "presentation.html" in Firefox I get the slides accurately. However, when export "presentations.org"  with Ctrl-c RB the html-page in Firefox is without slides. However, when I commented out ;;;(setq org-reveal-root "file:///~/reveal.js-master") in my .emacs, the export works!

Comment: Ah. Yes, that's the master link to your reveal.js installation. If you put the reveal folder in your home folder and renamed it to reveal.js-master it would also have worked. Without that setting it just looks in the project folder.

Comment: @Arboreus. That is exactly what I have done: I have the reveal.js-package in my home folder (~/reveal.js) and setq org-reveal-root "file:///~/reveal.js" in my .emacs. However, when I export ~/presentations/test.org with Ctrl-C RB, the test.html in my browser have no slides, purely running text. Still, following your first answer: having the reveal.js in ~/presentations/reveal.js works. Apparently, I do not manage to get the global link to my reveal.js-folder (in my home directory) to work.

Comment: OK, actually went and tested it. Put this code in your .emacs or evaluate it before exporting your presentation: (setq org-reveal-root "/home/treeman/reveal.js")  The issue, I think, is that org-reveal doesn't recognize the ~ syntax for home folders, so you have to be explicit and write out the full path. Good luck!

Comment: And, just to be explicit, leave off the file:// syntax. That's org specific, not Emacs specific.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it does not work. I will stick to the solution that you gave at the top and that works: putting the reveal.js in the same folder as the presentation.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by specifying where reveal.js was in customize-variable.

```
M-x customize-variable RET org-reveal-root RET
```

Then in the "Other directory path" put in the path to the reveal.js folder. In my case:

```
/home/james/Documents/reveal.js
```